# Map a share that runs on a server not joined to the windows domain

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, server-message-block, workgroup

We have a Windows domain. I have to set up a Windows server file share without joining the server to the domain and map the share as a drive on everyone's computer. They will all need RW access to the share.

I tried adding the "everyone" and "anonymous login" groups to the permissions tab and the shared tab in advanced sharing. The only way I have been able to do this is to create a local user account on the non domain joined server. Then on my domain joined computers I can map the drive but I select "connect as another user". Does anyone know of another way to allow this without using the local user account?

I did get the drive to map at some point having the default groups along with "anonymous" and "everyone" added to the permissions and sharing tabs but while trying to write to the drive I get a permission denied error.

Comment: When adding "everyone" you must also grant "full control" to everyone on both tabs. And check that permissions are inherited..

Comment: `We have a Windows domain. I have to set up a Windows server file share without joining the server to the domain.` - Why? Why did you not join this server to the domain? That seems like a good way to make things more complicated.

Comment: to somewhat echo @joeqwerty's remark, join your machine to the domain, things should then just work.

Comment: Those are the business requirements for this configuration. It is not for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this helpful link, it has given me what i need. The only thing different that I did was that i gave the "Guest" user account full access to the share.

https://web.archive.org/web/20220524195140/http://nikolar.com/2015/03/10/creating-network-share-with-anonymous-access/